# Aligned nested enumerate

Tags: enumerate, tasks

I'm trying to create a nested enumerate items as shown below. I cannot get the second level labels to align with the first level labels. Is there way to do this cleanly?

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \usepackage{amsmath}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*),label-width=4ex, before-skip=1.75ex]
    \task $9\tfrac{1}{3}$ km
    \task $1\tfrac{7}{8}$ hours
    \task $3\tfrac{1}{3}$ hours
    \task $11\tfrac{2}{3}$ km
    \end{tasks}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

For the second level list I've been using tasks and trying to align manually. However, I've noticed that each time I do this, I need to change the vertical spacing by sight - clearly not optimal!

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @DG'. I've fixed the question as directed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \compress
    \begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*),label-width=4ex, before-skip=1.75ex]
    \task $9\tfrac{1}{3}$ km
    \task $1\tfrac{7}{8}$ hours
    \task $3\tfrac{1}{3}$ hours
    \task $11\tfrac{2}{3}$ km
    \end{tasks}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Bernard! For some reason, when I put this code into my document, the task items are on the next line down from the number 1. Can you think of a reason why this might be happening?

Comment: @Auslander: No real idea. Maybe you don't have  the latest version of tasks? A simple suggestion: try changing the value of before-skip – the value this code uses was adjusted by trial and error.